# Get back my old Google+ URL

Tags: google-plus, url

How do I get my old Google+ URL to my new Google+ account after I deleted my old Google+ profile (not old Google account, only Google+)?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably out of luck. Google doesn't recycle user accounts of G+ URLs.